# Environment variable available for all processes

Tags: linux, docker, unix, environment-variables

I'm spawning new processes inside my container, and I found out that despite i set `PATH` environment variable on Dockerfile level by:

```
ENV PATH=/XXXX:$PATH
```

only old PATH value is available.

In otherword `ENV` affects only environment variables for what we execute by `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`.

What is the proper way to set environment variables for all new processes in this container?

Comment: That’s not true in my experience, and indeed [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) says ‘_environment variables set using `ENV` will persist when a container is run from the resulting image_’. Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: …for example: `printf 'FROM alpine\nENV foo=bar' | docker build -t test - && docker run --rm test sh -c 'echo $foo'` prints `bar`, as expected.

Comment: The `PATH` environment variable in particular may be set explicitly by shell initialization files in your image. Without a [mcve] it's hard to tell; please update your question to include something that reproduces the behavior you're asking about.

Comment: System calls like execve(2) allow the old process to specify the new process's environment, and most wrappers around this have something similar.  What code is spawning the new processes?  What leads you to believe `$PATH` is unchanged?